# Mockito 3 Wanted but not invoked

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to learn Mockito 3, I have looked almost all the results in google search, but couldn't find the working solution.
I am calling `processStudent` in a test case which on the basis of input internally calls another method `saveStudent` or `saveNullStudent`.

```
 public String processStudent(String student) {
    System.out.println("StudentService.processStudent: it will process Student = " + student);
    String StudentRes;
    if (Objects.isNull(student)) {
        StudentRes = saveNullStudent(student);
        return StudentRes;
    } else {
        StudentRes = saveStudent(student);
        return StudentRes;
    }
}

public String saveNullStudent(String student) {
    System.out.println("StudentService.saveNullStudent: it will process then save Student = " + student);
    return student;
}

public String saveStudent(String student) {
    System.out.println("StudentService.saveStudent: it will process then save Student = " + student);
    return student;
}
```

I need to test both the cases so my Test case is

```
 @Test
void saveStudentWithMockTest() {
    StudentService StudentService = mock(StudentService.class);
    StudentService.processStudent("studentA");
    verify(StudentService, times(1)).saveStudent("studentA");
}

@Test
void saveStudentWithNullMockTest() {
    StudentService StudentService = mock(StudentService.class);
    StudentService.processStudent(null);
    verify(StudentService, times(1)).saveNullStudent(null);
}
```

but I am getting

```
Wanted but not invoked:
studentService.saveNullStudent(null);
-> at StudentServiceTest.saveStudentWithNullMockTest(StudentServiceTest.java:21)

However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock:
studentService.processStudent(null);
-> at StudentServiceTest.saveStudentWithNullMockTest(StudentServiceTest.java:20)
```

Gradle file

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.6.2')
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:3.4.4'
}
```

I don't understand, isn't this is what mockito is for?

the whole point of this test case is not for a unit test but to test the behavior of `processStudent` method that as per input data if the value is null then `saveNullStudent` method is called or else `saveStudent` method is called.

what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call the `processStudent` on a mock object, this means, that the original code is not used. Therefore the `save` method is not invoked.

You need to change the mock, so the real method is invoked by using `thenCallRealMethod()`.

In your first test you have to add a line like:

```
when(StudentService.processStudent("studentA")).thenCallRealMethod()
```

In the second test it is similar, but with another parameter.
Maybe the syntax is not 100% correct, because I am writing this without any IDE support, but I think you get the idea.

You should learn what a mock object is first. Then the solution will make more sense.

Comment: HI @
yes if I update my test case like this then it is working.

@Test
    void saveStudentWithMockTest() {
        StudentService studentService = mock(StudentService.class);
        when(studentService.processStudent("studentA")).thenCallRealMethod();
        studentService.processStudent("studentA");
        verify(studentService, times(1)).saveStudent("studentA");
    }

but what if my saveStudent method was actually saving data in the database, and because now I am using thenCallRealMethod, then it will actually save in DB, isn't this defeat the whole purpose of mockito?

Comment: You don't need to call the real `saveStudent` and `saveNullStudent` methods, only the `processStudent` should use as the real method. Then the mocked methods for saving are used and you can check if they are called correctly - as you do in your tests. This should work ...

Answer (score 0):

You should only mock the dependencies of the class that you want to test.  By which I mean, if the `StudentService` class has any global variables like other service or repository classes those are the classes that you should mock.  The `StudentService` class itself should be real.  A better test in your case would be to check the output of the `processStudent` method for both test cases.  Eg:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class StudentServiceTest {

    private final StudentService studentService = new StudentService();

    @Test
    public void saveStudentWithMockTest() {
        String result = studentService.processStudent("studentA");

        assertThat(result).isEqualToIgnoringCase("studentA");
    }

    @Test
    public void saveStudentWithNullMockTest() {
        String result = studentService.processStudent(null);

        assertThat(result).isNull();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @space-cadet, yes I know that, but right now I don't have any other dependency in my StudentService class. right now I just want to verify the behavioral testing, that as per input data, if the value is null then saveNullStudent method is called or else saveStudent method is called.